# C# 'System.StackOverflowException'

Tags: c#, class, stack-overflow

I'm new to C#. I'm trying to create a class named 'Product'. It has some variables named "productName", "discountRate", "productPrice". I want to calculate new price with using productPrice(e.g. 6000) and discountRate(e.g. 10). If discountRate is 0, then it should return productPrice, if discountRate is not 0, then it should return the new price.

productPrice - ((productPrice * discountRate) / 100)

But I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
> occurred in Class_intro.dll

Here's my code:

```
using System;

namespace Class_intro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product product1 = new Product();
            product1.productName = "Huawei Notebook";
            product1.discountRate = 10;
            product1.productPrice = 6000;

            Product product2 = new Product();
            product2.productName = "Lenovo Notebook";
            product2.discountRate = 25;
            product2.productPrice = 4000;


            Product[] products = new Product[] { product1, product2 };

            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name: " + product.productName
                    + "\nProduct Price: " + product.productPrice
                    + "\nDiscount Rate: " + product.discountRate
                    + "\n-----------------");
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int discountRate { get; set; }
        public double productPrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (discountRate == 0)
                {
                    return productPrice;
                }
                else
                {
                    return productPrice - ((productPrice * discountRate) / 100);
                }
                
            }
            set { productPrice = value; }


        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Your setter for `productPrice` is calling itself. Perhaps you intended to have a separate backing field for this property. If so, you forgot to add it.

Comment: productPrice calls productPrice calls productPrice calls productPrice calls productPrice .... finally reads the [documentation for getters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/get)

Comment: Create a field (say `private double _productPrice;`) then change your getter and setter code for your property to reference that private field (for example, in the setter: `set { _productPrice = value; }`.  Remember a property is code that acts like data.  In your code for the property, you are referencing the property, which gets you into infinite recursion - until you stack runs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is referencing the property in both the getter and setter, which causes an infinite loop, but your design is a bit confusing since you use the same property for the "gross" product price and the "discounted" product price. I would just use a plain property for the product price and a separate read-only property for the discounted price. That also gets rid of the infinite loop:

```
class Product
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public int discountRate { get; set; }
    public double productPrice {get; set;}
    public double discountedPrice 
    {
        get
        {
            return productPrice - ((productPrice * discountRate) / 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need the `if (discountRate == 0)` case because mathematically it's the same, but if you want to keep it in there for readability that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear, you need to have a backing field for your productPrice property:

```
class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int DiscountRate { get; set; }
    private double productPrice;
    public double ProductPrice
    {
        get
        {
            if (DiscountRate == 0)
            {
                return productPrice;
            }
            else
            {
                return productPrice - ((productPrice * DiscountRate) / 100);
            }
            
        }
        set { productPrice = value; }

    }
}
```

Generally I use sentence case for properties and _ for start of private fields but camel case with lower case start for private fields is just as valid.  Best to pick something and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare another double to hold your "productPrice" value, you can return this on the get and set it on the set as you planned.

Try this:

```
using System;

namespace Class_intro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product product1 = new Product();
            product1.productName = "Huawei Notebook";
            product1.discountRate = 10;
            product1.ProductPrice = 6000;

            Product product2 = new Product();
            product2.productName = "Lenovo Notebook";
            product2.discountRate = 25;
            product2.ProductPrice = 4000;


            Product[] products = new Product[] { product1, product2 };

            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Product Name: " + product.productName
                    + "\nProduct Price: " + product.ProductPrice
                    + "\nDiscount Rate: " + product.discountRate
                    + "\n-----------------");
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int discountRate { get; set; }

        private double productPrice;
        public double ProductPrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (discountRate == 0)
                {
                    return productPrice;
                }
                else
                {
                    return productPrice - ((productPrice * discountRate) / 100);
                }

            }
            set { productPrice = value; }
        }
    }
}
```